# what is the use of -Xns option

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I found the following JVM argument in my working environment

-Xms12288m This specifies initial heap size

-Xmx12288m This specifies max heap size

one doubt here, If it reaches beyond this it will throw exception(Out of memory) ?

-Xns:3g what is this argument specifies?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try Google already?

Comment: -1 because the question does not show any research effort

Comment: It can't reach beyond this figure.  Technically it can't even reach this figure because you have two survivor spaces and only one can be used at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Here you find the[Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html#wp999534) for commandline options. this explains -Xns:

> -Xns sets the nursery size. the JRockit JVM uses a nursery when the generational garbage collection model is used, that is, when the dynamic garbage collector has determined that the generational garbage collection model should be used or when the static generational concurrent garbage collector ( -Xgc : gencon) has been selected. You can also use -Xns to set a static nursery size when running a dynamic garbage collector (-XgcPrio).

Answer (score 1):

You can check out many options here :
[Which arguments stand for what in JVM memory options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864293/which-arguments-stand-for-what-in-jvm-memory-options)

> -Xns: sets the nursery size. the JRockit JVM uses a nursery when the generational garbage collection model is used, that is, when the
>   dynamic garbage collector has determined that the generational garbage
>   collection model should be used or when the static generational
>   concurrent garbage collector ( -Xgc : gencon) has been selected. You
>   can also use -Xns to set a static nursery size when running a dynamic
>   garbage collector (-XgcPrio).

Answer (score 0):

Run java -X and it will print help on all available -X options