# How to list all non-standard options of a JVM?

Tags: java

I remember there is a way to list out all JVM non-standard options, including -XX ones, but I forget it and can't find it. Someone knows it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can get those without looking at the source of the JVM. See also: http://www.pingtimeout.fr/2012/05/jvm-options-complete-reference.html

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486375/print-all-jvm-flags