# Complete list of JVM options

Tags: jvm, java, jvm-hotspot

Besides [official documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) I have found only this [post](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.ru/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html). But it is quite old and incomplete (only `-XX` options available).
For example, I couldn't find `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax` option in none of them.

Where the complete list can be found if it exists?

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic but it's also a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486375/print-all-jvm-flags

Comment: And I think you're not likey to find a documentation that expose all `-XX` option, as stated in Oracle doc `Options that are specified with -XX are not stable and are subject to change without notice.` so a documentation would be hard to maintain. I guess they don't won't to struggle with that. The best you can have is probably http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html (replace unix by windows if you're on it)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version
```

to print all options and their defaults. If you have a debug build you can use this command to print comments for the various options as well:

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintFlagsWithComments -version
```

PS: There are descriptions for most of them in this blog post: http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.bg/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html