# UseSplitVerifier Java 7 to Java 9

Tags: java, maven, java-9, maven-surefire-plugin

We are converting an existing app from Java 7 to Java 9 and I'm trying to follow this page here for the minimum requirements: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw

When I try to run mvn clean install on a few of our components, I keep getting:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1\bin\java" --add-modules java.se.ee -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -jar
```

When I try to google UseSplitVerifier, I keep seeing things about StackMapTable or if UseSplitVerifier is safe to be used.  But I don't really know  what UseSplitVerifier is and what is the correct approach to build from J7 -> J9.

### Edit

My pom.xml has this plugin:

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.20.1</version>
```

Looking at the https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw link it says minimum is to use 2.20.1 so I thought that would be ok?  When I search my project, I don't see any `UseSplitVerifier` argument being passed so I'm not sure what is using that command except the surefire plugin.

Comment: Just to add to the details, what maven-surefire-plugin version are you using in your project? Would be good to see compiler plugin configuration as well for the command in logs. Also note that you shouldn't use `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` anymore. It has been deprecated since Java 8 and probably removed in Java9(*Unrecognized VM option 'UseSplitVerifier'*).

Comment: @nullpointer I'm not using that option when I run maven or in the pom.  Is there another way this is getting run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probable cause for your failure logs to start off investigating is that the flag,

```
-XX:-UseSplitVerifier
```

which seems to have been [deprecated with Java8](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-runtime-dev/2013-March/006287.html) itself, is no more supported in Java9 [source - [Complete list of JVM options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087831/complete-list-of-jvm-options/43087901#43087901])

You should ideally get rid of this flag while migrating since you wouldn't be needing this while compiling or executing the classes to the version 53 of Java SE(Java9).

---

***Edit***: There was a memory leak reported in the 2.20.1 version of surefire while executing tests via junit. You might want to be still using 2.19.1 which should still work fine with Java9 modules.